# Stackoverflow type of badge plugin giving warnings in Wordpress 3.5

Tags: plugins, php, wpdb, warnings

I modified an abandoned Stackoverflow form of badge plugin to work with Wordpress 3.4.2 and it does indeed. The full script for it is here: http://pastebin.com/Ta91zXiL

When upgrading to Wordpress v3.5, I receive these warnings when publishing a post (or post a comment):

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/rockhoist-badges/rh-badges.php on line 342 and defined in /public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 990

Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/rockhoist-badges/rh-badges.php on line 342 and defined in /public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 990

Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/rockhoist-badges/rh-badges.php on line 342 and defined in /public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 990

Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/rockhoist-badges/rh-badges.php on line 355 and defined in /public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 990

Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/rockhoist-badges/rh-badges.php on line 355 and defined in /public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 990

Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/rockhoist-badges/rh-badges.php on line 342 and defined in /public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 990

Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/rockhoist-badges/rh-badges.php on line 342 and defined in /public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 990

Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/rockhoist-badges/rh-badges.php on line 342 and defined in /public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 990

Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/rockhoist-badges/rh-badges.php on line 355 and defined in /public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 990

Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /public_html/wp-content/plugins/rockhoist-badges/rh-badges.php on line 355 and defined in /public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 990

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php:990) in /public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 876
```

So it seems to be related to lines 342 and 355:

```
function rhb_get_user_comment_count( $args = '' ) {

        global $wpdb;

        $comment_count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "comments
                WHERE user_id = " . $args['user_ID'] . "
                AND comment_approved = '1'" ) ); // line 342

        return $comment_count;
}

function rhb_get_user_post_count( $args = '' ) {

        global $wpdb;

        $post_count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts
                WHERE post_author = " . $args['user_ID'] . "
                AND post_status = 'publish'
                AND post_type = 'post'" ) ); // line 355

        return $post_count;
}
```

I have been trying to understand these warnings all day but failed. Can someone kindly assist me to fix this issue so that we can have a working version of this very useful badge system for WP 3.5?

Comment: I do not believe this question is an *exact duplicate* of the referenced question. The referenced question uses `$wpdb->prepare()` needlessly, and its solution is to *remove* `$wpdb->prepare()`. It does not address the change required for *proper usage* of `$wpdb->prepare()` in WordPress 3.5. This question does, and IMHO should be allowed to stand on its own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Lead developer Nacin answers this one](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/php-warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdb-prepare/):

> Hello plugin or theme author! You possibly found this post after
>   searching the Internet for the error above: “PHP Warning: Missing
>   argument 2 for wpdb::prepare().”
>
> So, this is a new warning in 3.5. No sites are broken, everything is
>   fine as before. But, this is indeed something you need to look at,
>   because you may be exposing your users to a possible SQL injection
>   vulnerability. Now that’s no fun!

Have a read of the rest, for further explanation.

As for rehabilitating your existing code:

```
$wpdb->prepare( 
    "
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "comments
    WHERE user_id = " . $args['user_ID'] . "
    AND comment_approved = '1'
    " 
)
```

First, clean it up by getting rid of the unnecessary string concatenation, and calling `$wpdb->comments` for the comments table:

```
$wpdb->prepare( 
    "
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM    $wpdb->comments
    WHERE   user_id = $args['user_ID']
    AND     comment_approved = '1'
    " 
)
```

Now, the warning has to do with this part of the query:

```
WHERE   user_id = $args['user_ID']
```

You need to replace `$args['user_ID']` with `$d`, and then use `$args['user_ID']` as the missing, second parameter:

```
$wpdb->prepare( 
    "
    SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM    $wpdb->comments
    WHERE   user_id = %d
    AND     comment_approved = '1'
    ",
    $args['user_ID'] // %d
)
```

The second one should be similar:

```
$wpdb->prepare( 
    "
    SELECT    COUNT(*)
    FROM      $wpdb->posts
    WHERE     post_author = %d
    AND       post_status = 'publish'
    AND       post_type = 'post'
    ",
    $args['user_ID'] // %d
)
```

Comment: Interesting. According to this article, I am calling $wpdb->prepare() with only one argument like `$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table" );` and I should be calling it like this: `$wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = %d", $id );`. By looking at my script, how would I make the following change?

Comment: See updated answer. You're basically treating it as an [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) call to format the untrusted data.

Comment: Excellent update. I will be adding the proposed edits and run tests to confirm if it functions accordingly. I am calling `$wpdb->prepare` in various places in my script, can you kindly help me detect if there are any other parts where it needs updates? The script is here: http://pastebin.com/Ta91zXiL Also, I plan to release this plugin publicly once I have fixed these issues and styled it better, can you please tell me how you would like to be credited for your contribution, `Chip Bennett`?

Comment: *"I am calling $wpdb->prepare in various places in my script, can you kindly help me detect if there are any other parts where it needs updates?"* - If you have specific questions about specific instances/usages of `$wpdb->prepare()`, I would just ask a new question for each, as appropriate. No personal credit is necessary. :) If it were my code, I would just put an @link to this WPSE question/answer, as reference.

Comment: You did this one well Chip, I have tested it and it works as noted. Excellent, I will be adding credit regardless as there have been various contributors to this plugin and I would like to credit everyone accordingly and thus establish a collaborative presence for whomever that actually reads credits lists ;) Upvoted and accepted.