# Problem since update 3.5

Tags: plugins, widgets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stackoverflow type of badge plugin giving warnings in Wordpress 3.5](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76512/stackoverflow-type-of-badge-plugin-giving-warnings-in-wordpress-3-5)

I have updated my wordpress website simpliblog.org 2 days ago. And now I can read that on top:  Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), called in /home/simplib/public_html/wp-content/themes/gonzo/includes/widget_areas.php on line 154 and defined in /home/simplib/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 990

I don't know what to do, I don't want to download and install wordpress 3.5 because I have changed the css.

Another problem : my website is in french and english and since the update my qtranslate plugin doesn't work. I can't post anything!! What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

### Short explanation

The [`$wpdb->prepare()` method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Examples) works similar to `sprintf()/printf()` and therefore needs more than one argument (else it's senseless to use it at all).

So if one of your plugins or the theme makes a DB call, which is prepared to protect you against cross script attacks and similar and doesn't do it properly, WordPress throws a message to notify you update that.

Repeat each step and reload. If it worked, you're done. If not, proceed to the next one.

1. Update all your plugins
2. Deactivate your theme and switch to Twenty*
3. Deactivate all of your plugins - activate each one, reload.

If you found the error and it was your own code, go and fix it. If it was a plugin, head over to the forum/Issue tracker and tell the author.

### The magic of search

A plain normal Google search for

> Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare()

reveals [hundreds of results](http://goo.gl/WaJx3) ...